# How To Check iPhone App User Rated Or Reviewed The App Or Not

Tags: iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

My iPhone App is now on App store from last week with 300+ downloads but only 3 user rate and review the app and now i am planning for Update So is there any way to check the user who is using the app is rate/review on App store or not ?
So if user is not yet review i can give an alert for review/rate. 
and if yes than not issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend you look into Appirater, it's a free GIT project that displays a `UIAlertView` automatically every 10 launches or every 8 days (numbers you are able to change) prompting the user to rate your app. It includes "review/rate, not now, and don't ask me again" buttons and it works very well, here's the link: [github.com/arashpayan/appirater](http://github.com/arashpayan/appirater)

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no way to find out if a specific user in your app gives your app a rating/review. Even after prompting a user to do so and they hit rate, there is no way to confirm that they have indeed left feedback of any kind.

I realize you want this information so that you can avoid prompting users that have already left a rating for your app, but in all honesty I would recommend you prompt them again. Considering it is an update, it is a different version of your application and the ratings for the latest version is segregated from the previous ones. Additionally, these users may have something new to say, so I think you are better off just prompting all users of any given version of your app at least once.

Comment: I am not looking like avoid prompting users. as i asked my app has 300 downloads and only 3 review/rate is there. I only looking how can i get another 297 review/rate (Good/bad it does not matter). Even with the help of this i can improve the user experience and want to give more entertainment.

Comment: @Keithbunts Don't expect as many reviews as downloads, personally I've noticed about a 1% review/rating rate on all my apps.

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle thanks but review/rate is require for better apps so is there any way to little bit prompt user for review/rate ?